# JQuery Bubble Popup: innerhtml hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the JQuery Bubble Popup library, trying to show a hidden div in the innerHtml variable. Right now I have this:

```
<div class="button"> Show stuff </div>
<div class="information"> foo </div>

<div class="button"> Show stuff </div>
<div class="information"> bar </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.information').hide();
        $('.button').CreateBubblePopup({
                                        position: 'bottom',
                                        align: 'center',
                                        width: '300',
                                        innerHtml: $(this).next(".information").html(),
                                        innerHtmlStyle: { color:'#000', 'text-align':'left', 'font-size':'110%' },
                                        themeName: 'grey',
                                        themePath: '/static/images/jquerybubblepopup-theme',
                                        selectable: true,
                                      });
        });


</script>
```

The thing is, it isn't working as I expected, the problem is in the line

```
innerHtml: $(this).next(".information").html(),
```

Because if I put this it works:

```
innerHtml: 'testing jquery bubblepopup',
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what the question is?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this line:

```
  innerHtml: $(this).next(".information").html(),
```

is that `this` is not referring to what you think it refers to.  I *think* you want it to refer to the current button being affected, but it doesn't - it's the `this` value that's in effect in the "ready" handler context.

What you can do (among several things) is use the ".each()" function:

```
$('.button').each(function() {
  $(this).CreateBubblePopup({
    position: 'bottom',
    align: 'center',
    width: '300',
    innerHtml: $(this).next(".information").html(),
    innerHtmlStyle: { color:'#000', 'text-align':'left', 'font-size':'110%' },
    themeName: 'grey',
    themePath: '/static/images/jquerybubblepopup-theme',
    selectable: true
   });
 });
```

Also you've got a stray comma at the end of the bubble popup parameter object, which will get you an error from IE.